# Como fazer um filtro de datas carregar os dados (em tempo de execução) de acordo com o que o usuário está digitando?

Tags: jquery

Tenho a tela abaixo e assim que o usuário for digitando a data, a *function* já ir carregando os dados.

Não sei qual evento jQuery usar e/ou se é algo mais detalhado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @dvd filtrar a tabele ja carregada, pq essa tabela vai trazer todos os pedidos para cliente, ai caso ele queria pesquisar uma data específica ou ciclo.

Comment: @dvd no caso pensei em data um split/subString na data e pegar só o que for ("mm/aaaa")

Comment: @dvd Ciclo seria ao perioado completo que o dado pertence. Exemplo "Pedido XPTO pertence ao ciclo "02/2018" é uma filtragem mais ampla.

Comment: Então vc quer filtrar apenas pelo ciclo?

Comment: @dvd Não, por data também. Porém o que eu preciso no momento é saber como fazer isso só para datas mesmo, depois vejo a questão do ciclo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue ir chamando a função que irá fazer o filtro usando o evento `input` (à medida que se vai digitando nos campos):

```
$(elementos).on("input"...
```

No exemplo abaixo, quando os campos "data inicial" e "data final" tiverem ambos 10 caracteres (que corresponde ao formato dd/MM/aaaa) irá disparar o `.each` que irá procurar em cada coluna `td:eq(1)` os 10 primeiros caracteres (`.substring(0,10)`) do texto da segunda `td` (`:eq(1)`) que é referente à data e comparar se ela está contida no *range* das datas dos `inputs`. Caso esteja, irá manter visível a respectiva linha (`$(this).closest("tr").show()`), caso contrário, escondê-la ((`$(this).closest("tr").hide()`)).

Considerando que o formato das datas vindas dos `inputs` seja...

```
dd/MM/aaaa
```

...para fazer a comparação de datas, eu alterei a ordem para...

```
aaaa/MM/dd
```

Para isso eu usei `.split("/")` usando os índices da array para criar uma nova data no formato acima, sendo assim, possível comparar datas.

**Exemplo do código:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#diaini, #diafim").on("input", function(){
      
      var dIni = $("#diaini").val();
      var dFim = $("#diafim").val();
      
      if(dIni.length == 10 && dFim.length == 10){
         
         var dIni_d = dIni.split("/");
         var dFim_d = dFim.split("/");
         
         dIni_d = dIni_d[2]+"/"+dIni_d[1]+"/"+dIni_d[0];
         dFim_d = dFim_d[2]+"/"+dFim_d[1]+"/"+dFim_d[0];
         
         $("#tabela tr").find("td:eq(1)").each(function(){
            
            var tab_dia = $(this).text().trim().substring(0,10);
            var tab_dia_d = tab_dia.split("/");
            tab_dia_d = tab_dia_d[2]+"/"+tab_dia_d[1]+"/"+tab_dia_d[0];
            
            tab_dia_d >= dIni_d && tab_dia_d <= dFim_d ?
            $(this).closest("tr").show()
            :
            $(this).closest("tr").hide();
            
         });
         
      }
      
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Data inicial:
<input maxlength="10" type="text" id="diaini">
Data final:
<input maxlength="10" type="text" id="diafim">
<br>

<table id="tabela" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         22/03/2018
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         21/03/2018
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         02/03/2018
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```